# How to communicate between Controllers?

Tags: angularjs, controllers

Here is plunker Link

http://plnkr.co/edit/X0fhStczchvxkHMUH9iq?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.Controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope){
$scope.handleClick = function(txt){
$rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent',txt)
}
});

app.Controller('secondCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope){
$scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) {
  $scope.msg =mass
 });
 });
```

Comment: It is `controller` not `Controller`. Check your console. Also your demo does not match what you are showing. In your demo, the event is broadcasted when the controller is instantiated and by that time the second controller has not been instantiated yet to listen to the event. It probably does not make sense to set an array as ngModel to the input. http://plnkr.co/edit/isCspC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

@PSL is correct. I've added the broadcast to a button click to show that's working.  Note that the array shows up in the input as a string "1, 2, 3".

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl"><button ng-click="broadcastMass()">Broadcast</button></div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('firstCtrl', function firstCtrl($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.broadcastClick = function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
    };
});
app.controller('secondCtrl',function secondCtrl($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) {
      $rootScope.msg = mass;
    });
});
```

[link to plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqwvB38VlyvwZlh4eP90?p=preview)